# How can I rewrite $\frac{1}{(1-z)^4}$ as a power series?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, power-series

I'm supposed to rewrite $\frac{1}{(1-z)^4}$ as a power series, using the Cauchy-Product. It is given that $|z| < 1$.

So far I have
\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{(1-z)^4} &= \left( \frac{1}{(1-z)^2} \right)^2\\
&= \left( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)z^n \right)^2\\
&=  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n} (n-k+1)z^{n-k}kz^k  \\
&=  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n} k(k+1)z^{n}  \\
\end{aligned}
First of all, I'm not sure whether every step was correctly so far. Additionally, I don't know how I can reduce that to a power series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third line should be
\begin{eqnarray*}
&=  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n} (n-k+1)z^{n-k} \color{red}{(k+1)}z^k  \\
\end{eqnarray*}
So we need to perform the sum
\begin{eqnarray*}
 \sum_{k=0}^{n} (n-k+1)(k+1) = -\sum_{k=0}^{n} k^2+ n \sum_{k=0}^{n} k +(n+1) \sum_{k=0}^{n} 1.
\end{eqnarray*}
Recall that
\begin{eqnarray*}
 \sum_{k=0}^{n}  k^2= \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}
\end{eqnarray*}
and we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
 \sum_{k=0}^{n} (n-k+1)(k+1) = \frac{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}{6}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Thanks a lot. It makes total sense, though I think you forgot the 2 in the last equation (2n+3) instead of (n+3)

Comment: In general we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{(1-x)^{k+1}} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{n+k}{k} x^n. \\
\end{eqnarray*}
There is some algebra to get from the second line to the fourth ... but I am pretty sure this expression is correct ?

Comment: I think I got it. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It looks right so far, though you're probably supposed to to get from the first line to the second by taking the Cauchy product of the series for $\frac1{1-z}$ with itself.

As for the last part, $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n} k(k+1)z^{n}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n} k(k+1)$$

and $$k(k+1)=\frac{k(k+1)(k+2)-(k-1)k(k+1)}3$$